# CrystalReport Load report failed

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have a windows application project (C# and .NET 2.0) that used Crystal Report 2008.  But I get error sometimes (it seems accidentally) in loading report. That error is:

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000020D): Unable to load report.
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
at SIA.DataTransfer.Forms.frmReport.GetStateReport(Int32 transferType)
```

please guide me. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this happen on your development machine? Or just production machines?

Comment: It's happen just in production machines. i'm sure report path is correct.

Comment: I've run into this problem before ... the first thing I would do is check to make sure the report path is correct.

Answer (score 19):

If your application is a standalone executable then this error is generated because you are not closing your report object properly when you are done with whatever you do. You might see this error running in your application as an ASP.NET app with a lot of users accessing your site simultaneously.

You can cause the error to appear sooner by tweaking this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CRYSTAL DECISIONS\10.0\REPORT APPLICATION SERVER\SERVER\PrintJobLimit
```

It normally is defaulted to 75.  For debugging you can set it to a smaller value and cause the error to appear sooner.

When you are done using a report object, call the .Close() method which will clean up the un-managed resources used.

There are those that mention to change the setting to -1.  This is a mistake, it will only cause other problems for an application that is long running.  The process will eventually run out of resources and start to fail in ways that will be even more difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: I just need to know if .dispose works as well as .close (I got an error while printing mine even using .dispose between prints). And error occurs mostly when I print it more than 75 times...

Comment: I wasn't able to find the key above in the specified location, though I did find it here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Business Objects\Suite 12.0\Report Application Server\. In that folder I found two: A) InprocServer\PrintJobLimit and B) Server\PrintJobLimit

Answer (score 4):

Increasing `CurrentJobLimit` is not the solution; this number will be reached if the counter is not reset.
**To avoid Job counter increase, you need to close the Crystal Report Document (`ReportSource.Close()`) programmatically.**

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource.Close();
 }
```

This is the only way to avoid continue increasing of opened report, that are counted by `CurrentJobLimit`

Comment: I'm using CR 13 and the CrystalReportViewer don't has the .Close() method. How do I close the document ?

Comment: @LukinhaRS not CrystalReportViewer but CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource has Close method.

Comment: @Apostrofix is the name of CrystalReportViewer Control that is in your page and that displays the report. If you drop a CrystalReportViewer control, the default name will be CrystalReportViewer1

Comment: @EmanueleGreco It's strange that I also don't have the `.Close()` method. In my application I create the CrystalReportViewer in the code, but even if using the visual designer, it still doesn't have the `.Close()` method. Is it only in ASP.NET, as I am using WinForms?

Comment: @Apostrofix not CrystalReportViewer but CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource has .Close() method.

Comment: @Apostrofix can you post some code? How do you set the report that has to be opened by viewer? I use this:   `reportDocument = new ReportDocument();  reportDocument.Load(reportFileName);`...  `CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument; reportDocument.ReadRecords();` ... `reportDocument.Close();`

Comment: @EmanueleGreco I have posted this thread earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643043/crystalreports-reportdocument-memory-leak-with-database-connections If you mean closing the `ReportDocument`, then I do that too, but I don't have a `crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource.Close()` method.

Answer (score 3):

I have verified [John Dyer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2862/john-dyer) solution, [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184309/crystalreport-load-report-failed/1588972#1588972), does not work in all cases.

I have also verified that reinstalling Crystal Runtime did no good for this particular error.

For my app this was only happening on Citrix installs of a stand-alone .exe, with embedded reports.  Before using the Crystal Report Viewer, I need to make sure that I've cleared out any report previously loaded in the viewer, as per John's instructions.  So, I'll wrote something (in VB) which looks like

```
Public Function ShowRpt(...) As Boolean
    ....
    CleanOutViewer()
    ....
End Function
```

where CleanOutViewer is:

```
Private Sub CleanOutViewer()
    If Not Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource() Is Nothing Then
        CType(Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource(), CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument).Close()
        CType(Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource(), CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument).Dispose()
        Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource() = Nothing
        GC.Collect()
    End If
End Sub
```

The calls after .Close() also had no effect (and were added as an alternate attempt to try to force the Crystal to release resources).

Comment: Also: using embedded resources rather than reports stored on the file system has no effect - I've never done so and am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Crystal Report Document needs to be manually disposed.

You should control the lifetime of all Reports in your application and call their Dispose before reaching the 75 limit.

There is a good approach on how to achieve this in this link:

http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2007/07/17/114008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The internet also suggests reinstalling the crystal report runtimes on the machines you are trying to open the report on (making sure that all locations have the same version).

Comment: thanx SeanJA. i should test this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `ReportDocument.Load` method was failing when using a mapped network share or UNC path and installing the crystal reports VS runtime on the file server fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to report properties and set "buildAction" to "Content".