# CrystalReports ReportDocument memory leak with database connections

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks, crystal-reports

I've spent the past few days looking into that and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a `c#` `WinForms` application that uses the `ReportDocument` to load a report and put it into the Crystal Report Viewer, so that the user can preview it. The purpose is to preview different statistics and the form is never closed. There's a timer that runs and loads different reports into the viewer.

While that happens the memory usage and handles (I can see them in the task manager) keep increasing. When the application is started, it uses around 30 MB and when it runs for 10 minutes, it is then using around 200 MB and it keeps  increasing.

I read a lot about this problem on the internet and I found that both the `ReportDocument` and the Viewer need to be closed and disposed. Unfortunately, that doesn't fix it. The connection type in the reports is `OLE DB(ADO)` as the data is retrieved from an `SQL Server` database.

Briefly what happens is that Form1 has a timer that when elapses it disposes the `Crystal Reports Viewer` and calls the garbage collector. And then loads the new report.

Here is the sample code that I have

Form1:

```
private ReportDocument rpt;

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer2.Enabled = false;

    try
    {
          panel1.Hide();

          if (rpt != null)
          {
               foreach (Table t in rpd.Database.Tables)
                        t.Dispose();
               rpt.Close();
               rpt.Dispose();
               rpt = null;
               GC.Collect();
           }

           panel1.Controls.Remove(CRVviewer);
           if (CRVviewer != null)
           {
               CRVviewer.Dispose();
               GC.Collect();
           }

           // The problem starts from here:

           var report = navigationbar1.CurrentNode;
           rpt = new ReportDocument();
           rpt.Load(@report.Path, OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);

           rpt.ReportOptions.EnableSaveDataWithReport = false;

           rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(report.UserId, report.Password);

           rpt.VerifyDatabase();

           // It ends here

           CRVviewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
           CRVviewer.ReportSource = rpt;
           CRVviewer.ShowLastPage();
           pagecount = CRVviewer.GetCurrentPageNumber();
           CRVviewer.ShowFirstPage();
           panel1.Controls.Add(CRVviewer);
           this.Update();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ProcessErrors(ex); 
    }
    finally
    {
         timer2.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The problem comes from the DB connections, because if I load a local report, it works fine. But what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's very tricky with *Crystal Report* to clean up the mess it creates with memory. (No offence to SAP)

You will have to first close and dispose the `ReportDocument`

```
rpt.Close();
rpt.Dispose();
```

And then assign nulls to the `ReportViewer` and dispose.

```
CRViewer.ReportSource=null;
CRViewer.Dispose();
CRViewer=null;
```

And finally, you have to do the two pass GC collect.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

> Please note that it is generally not recommended to call GC.Collect() but sometimes when memory is too much of an issue and third party COM component's like crystal report has issue with getting disposed properly, we may have to go this route.

Comment: Thanks, the memory usage seems to be fine now, but the handles in the task manager keep increasing.

Comment: EDIT: And after more testing, the memory usage is still increasing.

Comment: You might wanna try memory profiler like [dotMemory] (https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/)  This one is easy to use and have 5 days free trial. I solved my memory problem with the help of  this tool when I had similarly memory issue with Crystal reports. Moreover,  You also want to keep on eye on any subscribed events getting properly un-subscribed, specially if you have any crystal report reference in those events. I'll try to run your code and see if I could find any other issue? is that the complete code?

Comment: After the application was running for more than 20 hours, I can confirm that the above solution works. Probably this line `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` makes a huge difference.

Comment: I've been trying to get this viewer to release DB connections all day. This seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. 100% working. Please install the crystal report runtime version 13_0_26. It fixed for me. Took only 100 mb max to generate 100 reports.
The new version might not be compatible with ur nuget packages so update ur references accordingly.