# Crystal Report Error Exceed PrintJobLimit

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

> i'm Using Latest Crystal Report Version Service PAck 13 and Visual
>   Studio 2012 and Framework is 4 Client Profile some codes which i was
>   try but issue not solve  i was edit my registry for checking its
>   disposing or not but still error is coming  here is Registry where i
>   change printjob  Default is 75 and i replace with 2 for checking
>   purpose

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\REPORT APPLICATION SERVER\Server\PrintJobLimit
```

> below All code did not work clean the object from memory my Client
>   pissed me Please i need help how to solve it

```
 using (ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument())
                                    {
                                        doc.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\SaleFormat1.rpt");
                                        doc.SetDataSource(ds);
                                        doc.PrintToPrinter(Convert.ToInt32(nordt.Rows[0][2]), true, 1, 1000);
                                    }

ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
doc.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\SaleFormat1.rpt");
                                        doc.SetDataSource(ds);
                                        doc.PrintToPrinter(Convert.ToInt32(nordt.Rows[0][2]), true, 1, 1000);
doc.Close();
doc.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the "**.Net Framework 4 Client Profile**". Use the "**.Net Framework 4**" instead.

Also, try appending the following to your app config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: same issue on both framework if i use 4 ofcourse app.config update here is config code when i change my framework <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>

Comment: Clearly, the error indicates that you are using more than max print job limit,  you may try increasing your print job limit to say (200-300) in your registry setting. But that is just a temporary solution. You may have to try find out why is it exceeding the limit. One possible cause could be having a sub-report in a `detail section`.

Comment: Also you should dispose your crystal report property. See my other answer  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643043/crystalreports-reportdocument-memory-leak-with-database-connections/29643810#29643810] for how to dispose the crystal report properly.

Comment: #AdNewGuylnTown  still sam issue come  by this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643043/crystalreports-reportdocument-memory-leak-with-database-connections/29643810#29643810]

Comment: Did you increase your print job limit from 2 to say 300 in your registry setting? Set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Report Application Server\InprocServer value to 300

Comment: no i don't want to do this its tempory solved and also its take memory client have till machine with 1GB Ram so i don't want to do this else i read Sap documentation which mentioned u set limit -1 for unlimited but it take memory 
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/f053713e-3e3d-2c10-2a81-f79259e54023?QuickLink=support&overridelayout=true&43705587209382

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75686/discussion-between-anewguyintown-and-naeem-shah).